# PostgreSQL JSON: test if a value is contained in an array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a JSONB row which holds data in this form:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"key_1": "value1"} |
| 2 | {"another_key": "some_value"} |

Given another JSON structure like this `{"key_1": ["value1", "value2"]}`, what shall I use to get the first row to match a query?

I had no luck using the JSON operators of PostgreSQL in the doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Unless you're really using [long unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) PostgreSQL [9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html), refer to a more recent version of [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). If you're really on 9.5, consider an update.
2. If *first row to match a query* means you want the first by `id`, then add [`order by id limit 1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) at the end.
3. Version [12+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) has JSONPath `@@` predicate check and `@?` path exists operators. If you're looking for a row with a jsonb value resembling the one you showed (`key_1` with an array under it): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PxFk8w2f)

```sql
create table my_table(id,jsonb_column) as values
  (1::int, '{"key_1": "value1"}'::jsonb     )
, (2     , '{"another_key": "some_value"}'  )
, (3     , '{"key_1": ["value1", "value2"]}') ;

select * from my_table 
where jsonb_column @@ '$.key_1.type()=="array"' 
order by id limit 1;
```

| id | jsonb_column |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | {"key_1": ["value1", "value2"]} |

```sql
select * from my_table where jsonb_column @? '$.key_1[1]' order by id limit 1;
```

| id | jsonb_column |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | {"key_1": ["value1", "value2"]} |

4. Between versions [9.4.0 and 11.22](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) you can use `@>` object containment operator instead: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_3rR1peV)

```sql
select * from my_table where jsonb_column @> '{"key_1":[]}' order by id limit 1;
```

5. If you're looking for rows where there's `key_1` on the top level, and under it, there's any of the values in your array, [@Serg's example got it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185587/5298879). In version 14 and above, you can use `[key]` subscript

   ```sql
   select t1.*
   from my_table t1
   inner join jsonb_each(jsonb '{"key_1":["value1","value2"]}') as find(key,val)
     on find.val @> t1.jsonb_column[find.key]
   order by id limit 1;
   ```

   In earlier versions, you need the `->` accessor:

   ```sql
   select t1.*
   from my_table t1
   inner join jsonb_each(jsonb '{"key_1":["value1","value2"]}') as find(key,val)
     on find.val @> (t1.jsonb_column -> find.key)
   order by id limit 1;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use <@ comparison operator

```
with tbl(id, dat) as (
  select 1, '{"key_1": "value1"}'::jsonb union all
  select 2, '{"key_1": "valueX"}'::jsonb union all
  select 3, '{"key_X": "value1"}'::jsonb union all
  select 4, '{"key_1": "value2"}'::jsonb

),
prmkv as (
  select *
  from jsonb_each('{"key_1": ["value1", "value2"]}'::jsonb) 
)
select tbl.*
from tbl
join prmkv on (tbl.dat -> prmkv.key) <@ prmkv.value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first re-format/flatten the search structure. Here is a bit more complex one for genericity, `{"key_1":["value1","value2"], "key_2":["value21","value22","value23"]}`

```sql
select l.j 
from jsonb_each('{"key_1":["value1","value2"],"key_2":["value21","value22","value23"]}'),
lateral (
  select jsonb_build_object(key, item) j 
  from jsonb_array_elements(value) item
 ) l;
```

| result |
| --- |
| {"key_1": "value1"} |
| {"key_1": "value2"} |
| {"key_2": "value21"} |
| {"key_2": "value22"} |
| {"key_2": "value23"} |

and then use it in a more or less trivial query

```sql
select * from the_table where data @> any
(
 select l.j 
 from jsonb_each('{"key_1":["value1","value2"],"key_2":"value21","value22","value23"]}'),
 lateral (select jsonb_build_object(key, item) j from jsonb_array_elements(value) item) l
)
order by id limit 1;
```

DB Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iKQ1JJ2CGkwVkGseH3RMbU/0)